# Clean install of Ubuntu Karmic, Ruby 1.8.7 (2009-04-08 patchlevel 160), jkraemer-acts_as_ferret (0.4.4), Rails 2.3.4 -- Errors with AAF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-ferret

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Karmic, Ruby and Rails. I checkout out a working (production) application. Created the databases and ran the rake tasks. Made sure I had all the required gems of which acts_as_ferret by Jens Krämer was one of them.

Everything appears to be installed correctly. 
The gems are listed in environment.rb including AFF.

When I run rake I get the following error:

```
no such file to load -- ferret
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jkraemer-acts_as_ferret-0.4.4/lib/acts_as_ferret.rb:25
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/home/pp/ruby-dev/production-app/config/environment.rb:18
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
no such file to load -- ferret
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jkraemer-acts_as_ferret-0.4.4/lib/acts_as_ferret.rb:25
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:169:in `process'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/home/pp/ruby-dev/production-app/config/environment.rb:18
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
Missing these required gems:
 jkraemer-acts_as_ferret  ~> 0.4.4

You're running:
 ruby 1.8.7.160 at /usr/local/bin/ruby
 rubygems 1.3.5 at /home/pp/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems./usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jkraemer-acts_as_ferret-0.4.4/lib/acts_as_ferret.rb:25
```

I have no idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is not the best piper? 
From what I can see and having used AAF before just try installing ferret

```
sudo gem install ferret
```

You can find a good tutorial here:
http://railsenvy.com/2007/2/19/acts-as-ferret-tutorial

Comment: thinking about it - not sure why ferret was not automatically installed as a dependency